# Get name of Xcode Project in actual code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

So you know the part of the project that is "MyNameGoesHere.app" or "MyNameGoesHere.xcodeproj" - is there a way to get the MyNameGoesHere part via objective-c code?

I can get all kind of device info from UIDevice messages but I can't figure out how to get project/app name.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to obtain this?

Comment: I want to add it to an XML file I am outputting.

Comment: it would be much easier to use a #define XML_OUT AppName then retrieve this information or just an NSString

Comment: Are you going to have different build targets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking at the bundle's InfoDictionary. You can get the app's name via the following code:

```
NSDictionary *info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *bundleName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]];
```

Answer (score 6):

`CFBundleDisplayName` doesn't work anymore. Use:

```
NSString *bundleName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];
```